# Autoscaling Kubernetes based on log based metrics

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-monitoring, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I use Autopilot on GKE. I've created some log based metrics that I'd like to use to scale up pods.

To begin with - I'm not sure if it's great idea - the metric is just number of records in DB to process... I have a feeling using logs to scale app might bring in some weird infinite loop or something....

Anyhow - I've tried entering `logging.googleapis.com|user|celery-person-count` as an external metric and got `HPA cannot read metric value`. Installed Stackdriver adapter but not too sure how to use it either.

Comment: Any chance you can post the commands you used to install the Stackdriver Custom Metrics Adapter?

Comment: @GariSingh I've deployed Stackdriver Adapter using same steps as someone posted [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69625052/1272555)

Comment: My assumption it will allow GKE to read custom metrics from anywhere, including logging.googleapis.com.

Comment: Some tutorials call for executing `kubectl get --raw "/apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1" | jq` but that just returned empty `resources` array.

Comment: I added an answer below with the steps required to deploy the Stackdriver Custom Metrics Adapter on Autopilot clusters.  The steps are from the tutorial I wrote on a similar topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GKE Autopilot clusters have [Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity) enabled for consuming other GCP services, including Cloud Monitoring.

You'll want to follow the steps [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/workload-metrics-autoscaling#step3) in order to deploy the Custom Metrics Adapter on Autopilot clusters.

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding \
    --clusterrole cluster-admin --user "$(gcloud config get-value account)"

kubectl create namespace custom-metrics

kubectl create serviceaccount --namespace custom-metrics \
custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter

gcloud iam service-accounts create GSA_NAME

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding PROJECT_ID \
    --member "serviceAccount:GSA_NAME@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
    --role "roles/monitoring.viewer"

gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
  --role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser \
  --member "serviceAccount:PROJECT_ID.svc.id.goog[custom-metrics/custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter]" \
  GSA_NAME@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com

kubectl annotate serviceaccount \
  --namespace custom-metrics custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter \
  iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account=GSA_NAME@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com

kubectl apply -f manifests/adapter_new_resource_model.yaml
```

Given that you've already deployed the adapter, you'll want to delete the deployment first, although you might just be able to run the steps starting at `gcloud iam ...`

You'll need to replace GSA_NAME with a name of your choosing and PROJECT_ID with your Google Cloud project ID.

Comment: I kinda see where you coming from - I indeed skipped some of the steps before kubectl apply. Initially it did throw some permission errors which my GCP admin was able to resolve. I assumption was that steps are only required in specific circumstances where certain permissions aren't present.

Comment: So are you saying it's unable to read metrics because of some lacking permissions? Is there a way I can I debug the actual cause?

Comment: Was able to use the link above to correctly deploy adapter, however k8s wont scale because of data type of metric.

Answer (score 0):

**Custom metrics**

GitHub [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/tree/master/custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter):

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding \
    --clusterrole cluster-admin --user "$(gcloud config get-value account)"
```

resource : `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/master/custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter/deploy/production/adapter_new_resource_model.yaml`

Deploying application with metrics

```
git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes-engine-samples.git
cd kubernetes-engine-samples/custom-metrics-autoscaling/direct-to-sd
```

HPA example

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: custom-metric-sd
  namespace: default
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: custom-metric-sd
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
  - type: Pods
    pods:
      metric:
        name: custom-metric
      target:
        type: AverageValue
        averageValue: 20
```

You can check out this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/autoscaling-metrics#custom-metric_5) for more information.

if your workload running top of VM or not on K8s use the external metrics instead of custom.

Refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/custom-and-external-metrics) on Custom and external metrics for autoscaling workloads .

Comment: Unsure how this answers my question. Example uses `custom-metric` which is I assume is project-unique metric name? So should I use celery-person-count in my case as metric name (even if it's actual name is `logging.googleapis.com/user/celery-person-count`)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , Horizontal Pod Autoscaling can be done using metric values. If your application is running in Kubernetes then you must use a custom metric for Autoscaling and if your application is not running in Kubernetes then you must use External metric for Autoscaling.

A custom metric can be selected for any of the following:

- A particular node, Pod, or any Kubernetes object of any kind,
  including a CustomResourceDefinition (CRD).
- The average value for a metric reported by all Pods in a Deployment.

  Refer this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/custom-and-external-metrics#custom_metrics) for detailed explanation of using custom
  metric for Horizontal Pod Autoscaling.

Comment: Metric already exists, but when specifying I encounter error as above. How do I debug it? Can k8s read metrics from logging.googleapis.com at all?

Comment: To inspect your metric and see if the metric is filtering logs 
Go to the **Logs-Based Metrics** page:
In the User-defined metrics pane, you see the user-defined logs-based metrics in the current Cloud project:
To view the data in a logs-based metric, click the three dots in the metric's row and select **View in Metrics Explorer** and  **View logs for metric**.